# wpf for win7/win10, how to get icon/button size on taskbar at runtime? especially when DPI or something related changed

Tags: wpf, windows, taskbar

wpf for win7/win10, how to get icon/button size on taskbar at runtime?  especially when DPI or something related changed. i see the old way from Win32 doesn't work anymore. can i just follow the size of "Task" button on the taskbar.

```
IntPtr hDesktop = GetDesktopWindow();
IntPtr hTray = FindWindowEx(hDesktop, IntPtr.Zero, "Shell_TrayWnd", null);
IntPtr hReBar = FindWindowEx(hTray, IntPtr.Zero, "ReBarWindow32", null);
IntPtr hTask = FindWindowEx(hReBar, IntPtr.Zero, "MSTaskSwWClass", null);
IntPtr hToolbar = FindWindowEx(hTask, IntPtr.Zero, "ToolbarWindow32", null);

//IntPtr hToolbar = FindWindowEx(hTray , IntPtr.Zero, "Task", null);
//GetWindowInfo(hToolbar , ref pwi);
```

Comment: one more thing, on win10, GetWindowInfo for "Task" button, the size is always 40*48, no matter how "the Scale and layout" changed. i didn't find any info from msdn how the taskbar constructed after Vista.

Comment: something related: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6c00a205-b08f-4f29-bf9e-c84fbb13f506/create-icons-for-windows-10-taskbar?forum=windowsuidevelopment

Answer (score 0):

In Delphi maybe like this :

```
var
hTray,hReBar,hTask,hTollbar : HWND;
TTray,TReBar,TTask,TToolbar : TRect;

hTray := FindWindow("Shell_TrayWnd", nil);
hReBar := FindWindowEx(hTray, 0, "ReBarWindow32", nil);
hTask := FindWindowEx(hReBar, 0 "MSTaskSwWClass", nil);
hToolbar := FindWindowEx(hTask, 0, "ToolbarWindow32", nil);
GetWindowRect(HWND,TTray); //usage : TTray.Width .. TTray.Height ..  ETC
```